# Методы защиты от спама

Tags: ddos, php

Какие лучше использовать методы от спама и DDOS-атак? Есть что понадёжней капчи?

Comment: вручную обрабатывать, 100% надежность

Answer (score 2):

Регистриция с подтверждением через моб. телефон, Аудио капча